# Hidden Field on a Master Page - Adding a value in vb code of an ascx control

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, ascx, findcontrol

I'm currently trying to set a hidden field value which is located on a master page.  I am trying to set this value from a asc.vb file which is located on my child page

ascx.vb:

```
Dim PortalReq as New HiddenField()
portalReq.ID = "portalReq"
portalReq.Value = "aaaaa"
TryCast(Me.Page.FindControl("aspnetForm"),HtmlForm).Control.Add(portalReq)
```

When I run this page an error comes up with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I have looked on forums for information about this problem and can't seem to fix this.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Me.Page.Master.FindControl instead of Me.Page.FindControl

Comment: Thanks.  This was a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Me.Parent` instead of `Me.Parent.page`